# gke cluster deployment with custom network

Tags: deployment, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a yaml file to deploy gke cluster in a custom network I created. I get an error

JSON payload received. Unknown name \"network\": Cannot find field."

I have tried a few names for the resources but I am still seeing the same issue

```
resources:
- name: myclus
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    network: projects/project-251012/global/networks/dev-cloud
    zone: "us-east4-a"
    cluster:
      initialClusterVersion: "1.12.9-gke.13"
      currentMasterVersion: "1.12.9-gke.13"
      ## Initial NodePool config.
      nodePools:
      - name: "myclus-pool1"
        initialNodeCount: 3
        version: "1.12.9-gke.13"
        config:
          machineType: "n1-standard-1"
          oauthScopes:
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite
          preemptible: true
## Duplicates node pool config from v1.cluster section, to get it explicitly managed.
- name: myclus-pool1
  type: container.v1.nodePool
  properties:
    zone: us-east4-a
    clusterId: $(ref.myclus.name)
    nodePool:
      name: "myclus-pool1"
```

I expect it to place the cluster nodes in this network.

Answer (score 0):

The network field needs to be part of the cluster spec. The top-level of properties should just be `zone` and `cluster`, `network` should be on the same indentation as initialClusterVersion. See more on the [container.v1.cluster API reference page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters)

Your manifest should look more like:

EDIT: there is some confusion in the API reference docs concerning deprecated fields. I offered a YAML that applies to the new API, not the one you are using. I've update with the correct syntax for the basic v1 API and further down I've added the newer API (which currently relies on gcp-types to deploy.

```
resources:
- name: myclus
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    projectId: [project]
    zone: us-central1-f
    cluster:
      name: my-clus
      zone: us-central1-f
      network: [network_name]
      subnetwork: [subnet]   ### leave this field blank if using the default network
      initialClusterVersion: "1.13"
      nodePools:
      - name: my-clus-pool1
        initialNodeCount: 0
        config:
          imageType: cos
- name: my-pool-1
  type: container.v1.nodePool
  properties:
    projectId: [project]
    zone: us-central1-f
    clusterId: $(ref.myclus.name)
    nodePool:
      name: my-clus-pool2
      initialNodeCount: 0
      version: "1.13"
      config:
        imageType: ubuntu
```

The newer API (which provides more functionality and allows you to use more features including the v1beta1 API and beta features) would look something like this:

```
resources:
- name: myclus
  type: gcp-types/container-v1:projects.locations.clusters
  properties:
    parent: projects/shared-vpc-231717/locations/us-central1-f
    cluster:
      name: my-clus
      zone: us-central1-f
      network: shared-vpc
      subnetwork: local-only   ### leave this field blank if using the default network
      initialClusterVersion: "1.13"
      nodePools:
      - name: my-clus-pool1
        initialNodeCount: 0
        config:
          imageType: cos
- name: my-pool-2
  type: gcp-types/container-v1:projects.locations.clusters.nodePools
  properties:
    parent: projects/shared-vpc-231717/locations/us-central1-f/clusters/$(ref.myclus.name)
    nodePool:
      name: my-clus-separate-pool
      initialNodeCount: 0
      version: "1.13"
      config:
        imageType: ubuntu
```

Another note, you may want to modify your scopes, the current scopes will not allow you to pull images from gcr.io, some system pods may not spin up properly and if you are using Google's repository, you will be unable to pull those images.

Finally, you don't want to repeat the node pool resource in both the cluster spec and separately. Instead, create the cluster with a basic (default) node pool, for all additional node pools, create them as separate resources to manage them without going through the cluster. There are very few updates you can perform on a node pool, asside from resizing

Comment: Patrick I modified the node pool part in the manifest and I am currently getting this ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1568298555753-5925bf65143be-b311958e-826aaeec]: errors:
- code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
  location: /deployments/myclus-2/resources/myclus-pool1->$.properties
  message: '"": domain: validation; keyword: properties; message: required property(ies)
    not found; missing: ["clusterId","zone"]; required: ["clusterId","zone"]'

Comment: Looks like they haven't actually deprecated the node pool yet. Funny enough, the docs for these APIs aren't 100%. Jeep your current node pool co fig for now, it will change eventually though so keep the new syntax in mind

Comment: Error in Operation [operation-1568317977011-592607bea270a-5e00f3bc-cad3eb1e]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/myclus-0/resources/myclus-pool2
  message: '{"ResourceType":"container.v1.nodePool","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"message":"Not
    found: projects/projectearth-251012/zones/us-east4-a/clusters/myclus.","status":"NOT_FOUND","statusMessage":"Not
 Found","requestPath":"https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectearth-251012/zones/us-east4-a/clusters/myclus/nodePools","httpMethod":"POST"}}'

Comment: Now receiving this error even though all seems fine.
Error  Operation [operation-1568319955670-59260f1da1574-02f3d3bf-1305e804]:
-code: RESOURCE_ERR
  location: /deployments/myclus-0/resources/myclus-pool1
 '{"ResourceType":"container.v1.nodePool","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"message":"Not
    found: projects/projectearth-251012/zones/us-east4-a/clusters/myclus.","status":"NOT_FOUND","statusMessage":"Not
Found","requestPath":"https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectearth-251012/zones/us-east4-a/clusters/myclus/nodePools","httpMethod":"POST"}}'

Comment: Apologies for my last comment, I was writting on my phone.   
are you using a reference in your nodePool spec? It looks like a race condition where the nodePool is being created at the same time as the cluster so the nodePool is looking to link to the nodePool but can't find it

Comment: I also recommend editing or removing your comments to hide your project ID

Comment: thanks those are not real project IDs. I understand what you mean